# Pyspark use sql.transform to nullify all empty strings in a column containing an array of structs

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column in a pyspark df that contains an array of maps like the below:

```json
[{"address": "Fadden", "city": "", "country": "", "note": "", "stateProvince": "Queensland"}]
```

`df.printSchema()` returns the following for the column:

```
 |-- constituencies: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- address: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- note: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- stateProvince: string (nullable = true)
```

And I want to nullify all those empty strings. So I thought this would be a perfect problem to solve with `F.transform(col, f)`

So I created the function, and then I use it in the transform expression like below:

```
def nullify_vals(d):
  def nullify_string(str_):
    if str_.strip() == "":
      return None
    return str_.strip()
  
  return (
    dict((k, nullify_string(v)) for k, v in d.items())  
  )
```

Note that the above works when tested on a dictionary:

```
dd = {"my": "map", "is": "", "not": "   ", "entierly": "  empty , right?"}
d_cln = nullify_vals(dd)  
d_cln["not"] is None # returns True
```

But when I then use it in Pyspark, it gives me an error:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
result = kyclean.select(F.transform("constituencies", nullify_vals))
```

> TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

These are the last lines of the stacktrace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-899394298900126>:1, in <module>
----> 1 result = kyclean.select(F.transform("constituencies", nullify_vals))

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py:4260, in transform(col, f)
   4214 def transform(col, f):
   4215     """
   4216     Returns an array of elements after applying a transformation to each element in the input array.
   4217 
   (...)
   4258     +--------------+
   4259     """
-> 4260     return _invoke_higher_order_function("ArrayTransform", [col], [f])

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py:4209, in _invoke_higher_order_function(name, cols, funs)
   4206 expr = getattr(expressions, name)
   4208 jcols = [_to_java_column(col).expr() for col in cols]
-> 4209 jfuns = [_create_lambda(f) for f in funs]
   4211 return Column(sc._jvm.Column(expr(*jcols + jfuns)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `nullify_vals` should take a Column object of type StructType as your array elements are structs. But you're passing a normal python objects.

Try rewriting it like this instead:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Column

def nullify_vals(struct_col: Column, fields: List[str]) -> Column:
    for f in fields:
        struct_col = struct_col.withField(
            f,
            F.when(F.trim(struct_col[f]) == "", None).otherwise(struct_col[f])
        )

    return struct_col
```

For each field in the inner struct, we use column `withField` method to update it, if it's equal to empty string then we set it to null.

Applied to your input example:

```
json_str = '{"constituencies":[{"address":"Fadden","city":"","country":"","note":"","stateProvince":"Queensland"}]}'
df = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([json_str]))
```

You can get the list of `constituencies` struct fields from dataframe schema:

```
constituencies_fields = df.selectExpr("inline(constituencies)").columns

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "constituencies",
    F.transform("constituencies", lambda x: nullify_vals(x, constituencies_fields))
)

df1.show(truncate=False)
#+----------------------------------------+
#|constituencies                          |
#+----------------------------------------+
#|[{Fadden, null, null, null, Queensland}]|
#+----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I see. Let me try.

Comment: THANK YOU. This was extremely educational for me thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm still looking into the error you got and I'll update the post when I figure out what's wrong. In the meantime, you can do something like this to work around it

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

schema = ArrayType(
    StructType([
      StructField('address', StringType()),
      StructField('city', StringType()),
      StructField('country', StringType()),
      StructField('note', StringType()),
      StructField('stateProvince', StringType()),
  ]), True)
nullify_udf = udf(lambda arr: [[(v if v.strip() != "" else None) for v in area] for area in arr], schema)

result = kyclean.withColumn('constituencies', nullify_udf('constituencies'))
```

---

The specific error you got is saying that you can't call `d.items()` as a function and the input function really needs to be working on the Column object `d` that gets passed in.

The description of [`pyspark.sql.functions.transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html) says, "Returns an array of elements after applying a transformation to each element in the input array."

But inside the description of the accepted function, `f`, it says, "...and can use methods of `Column`, functions defined in `pyspark.sql.functions` and `Scala UserDefinedFunctions`. `Python UserDefinedFunctions` are not supported (SPARK-27052)." So it can't take in custom `Python UserDefinedFunctions` yet, which is sort of what you were trying to do.

Comment: but i am applying transform on an array column, an array of maps.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it wasn't clear from the original question description. I'm taking a look at it again now.