# Replace empty strings with None inside a column of Array type in a Spark Dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

Say you have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('test1', 7,['','hi',''], ['','',0]),
    ('', 14, ['','',6,''],[98,0,'',9])
], ["a", "b","c","d"])
df.show()
```

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'test1' | 7 | ['','hi',''] | ['','',0] |
| '' | 14 | ['','',6,''] | [98,0,'',9] |

Is there a way to replace all of the empty strings inside the array columns (C and D) with None/null? It would end up looking like the following:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'test1' | 7 | [Null,'hi',Null] | [Null,Null,0] |
| Null | 14 | [Null,Null,6,Null] | [98,0,Null,9] |

They key is I need to keep the positional value in each array, but I would like to have Null values instead of empty strings inside the arrays.

I have been able to turn the columns that are not arrays to None with the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df=df.select([F.when(F.col(c)=="",None).otherwise(F.col(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns])
```

I have looked at the array functions in databricks documentation here:
https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-functions-builtin-alpha.html

Using array_remove() I could remove all of the empty strings within the arrays, but again the challenge being I need to keep the positional values of each array with a Null value. I cannot just remove the strings without replacing the value. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: please [edit] your question with a reproducible constructor for your input

Comment: Try to use [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/api/sql/index.html#transform)

Comment: Don't know if it's a duplicate, but it does look similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71193469/12846804

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the `transform` function to apply a spark transformation to every element of an array:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, ["a", "", "b"]),
    (2, ["", "", "c"])
], ["id", "list"])
df.show()
```

```
+---+--------+
| id|    list|
+---+--------+
|  1|[a, , b]|
|  2| [, , c]|
+---+--------+
```

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
result = df.select(F.transform(F.col("list"),
    lambda x: F.when(x == "", F.lit(None)).otherwise(x)
  ).alias("list"))
result.show()
```

```
+---------------+                                                               
|           list|
+---------------+
|   [a, null, b]|
|[null, null, c]|
+---------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think to use transform that is exactly what I was looking for